# What sets User.Identity.IsAuthenticated in an ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I'm using the Facebook C# SDK, and I authenticate the user by their Facebook account. Once I've performed all the checks to "authenticate" them, I call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, false);`

Does performing that call allow me to have access to `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` within my actions? What about if I didn't make that call?

I have some actions that will return different views based on their authentication status, and want to make sure `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is reliable in an MVC 4 app.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is the [FormsAuthentication HTTP module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationmodule.aspx) that is registered and which executes on each request. This module is automatically registered when you specify `mode="Forms"` in your web.config's `<authentication>` tag. It is this same module which intercepts all 401 responses and automatically redirects the user to the LogOn page (which sometimes is not a desired behavior as the end result is HTTP status code of 200).

So to answer your questions:

> Does performing that call allow me to have access to
>   User.Identity.IsAuthenticated within my actions? What about if I
>   didn't make that call?

Not exactly. This call only emits the forms authentication cookie to the response. It is the HTTP module which is responsible for intercepting the request and if this request contains the cookie it will set the `User.Identity`.

Comment: Thank you, great answer. Let's say the visitor is brand new to the site, no auth cookie. Will `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` be false, or null? Then, so long as the FormsAuth HTTP module can read/validate the FormsAuth cookie, `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` will be true?

Comment: User.Identity is never null. But User.Identity.IsAuthenticated will be false.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Not only did you answer my question, but I more fully understand formsauth now, really appreciate that.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, will you please favor mentioning any article which covers the whole life cycle of mvc. I digged into  mvc life cycle but it was not detailed one. I want to clear my concepts about each module and entire application and request life cycle.

Comment: @Darin in form authentication, after clicking login button and being successfully authenticated from db, what happens that set the user identity, is it any module/ handler etc. And if nit use default membership  then what should be done in order to set identity? Is set authcookie is responsinle for that?